# Azure WIndows Server 2012 User account creation for Ftp server

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012

I have created a Windows Server 12 VM on Azure platform. And I created Ftp server on IIS server in the VM. The Ftp server is publically accessible using all users accounts. Currently I have only admin user account. I am trying to create couple of more user accounts & Ftp servers and assign each user to specific Ftp server.

I tried to create user account via **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools->Local Users and Group->New User**, but it does not allow me to progress. It just throws unknown error.

Any idea over how shall I create new user account so that it can be publically used for Ftp service authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to create new user from **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools->Local Users and Group->New User**. 
The unknown error was thrown because of password was not strong and entered invalid chars in Description, Full name textboxes. The error message from Win Server did not help at all.